# Inferring certain facts from transposition and resolution rule of propositional logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have following noted in my notebook:

1. **Transposition theorem** (I hope thats what its called)
   $(A\wedge B)\vee (\neg A\wedge C)=(A\vee C)\wedge(\neg A\vee B)$
2. **Consensus rule for transposition theorem** 
   $(A\wedge B)\vee (\neg A\wedge C)\vee (B\wedge C)=(A\wedge B)\vee(\neg A\wedge C)$
3. **Resolution rule**
   $(A\vee C)\wedge(\neg A\vee B)\rightarrow (B\vee C)$

Does this imply following?

**a.** From 2: $((A\wedge B)\vee(\neg A\wedge C))\rightarrow (B\wedge C)$
**b.** From 1 and 3: $(A\wedge B)\vee(\neg A\wedge C)\rightarrow (B\vee C)$

Its seems that these are obvious, however no book says states them explicitly. So, just confirming.

Comment: Doesn't $A=T,B=T,C=F$ contradict (a)? Maybe a typo since the LHS of (a) and (b) are the same?

Comment: Please let me use boolean algebra notation LHS=TT+FT=T and RHS=(T+F)(F+T)=T. Isnt it same? Prepared [logic table for LHS on wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(A+AND+B)+OR+(NOT+A+AND+C)). Not able to prepare same for [RHS](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(A+OR+C)(!A+OR+B)).

Comment: The RHS of (a) is false with the example I gave?

Comment: Resolution and consensus (in the propositional context) denote the same theorem. @Shuri2060 the RHS is in CNF.  Just apply distributivity.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi I'm confused - we have $T\implies F$ with the example for (a)? (ignore the previous comment on (b) - I misread it)

Comment: @Shuri2060 sorry I thought you were saying about (1)...

Comment: @FabioSomenzi I dont get how resolution and consensus are same. Resolution talks about implication ($\rightarrow$), whereas consensus talks about equality ($=$). Tell me what should I reduce to what to realize both are same...Didnt get "Just apply distributivity". Apply distributivity to what? to get what?

Comment: Because of duality of Boolean algebras, you also have that $B \wedge C \rightarrow (A \wedge B) \vee (\neg A \wedge C)$.  Besides, one of the basic properties of Boolean algebras is that $A \rightarrow B$ if and only if $A \vee B = B$.

Comment: Am really not getting how 2 and 3 state the same fact. Feels as if am a primary school student of logic. I know that, to find dual of a function, we change conjunction to dis-junction and vice versa; and 1s to 0s and vice versa. Dont know if there is other procedure for dealing with implication ($\rightarrow$) while finding dual. Are you getting $B∧C→(A∧B)∨(¬A∧C)$ by applying dual to 3)? Will appreciate more details or at least a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Statement: $(A\wedge B)\vee (\neg A\wedge C)\vee (B\wedge C)\Rightarrow (A\wedge B)\vee(\neg A\wedge C)\rightarrow (B\wedge C)$

Proof (of not being the case): Let's do this with a truth table, I will just use the shortest formula.

\begin{array}{ccc|cccc}
A & B & C & A\land B & \neg A \land C & B\land C\\
1 &1&1   &1&0 &1\\ 
1 &1&0   &1&0 &0\\
1 &0&1    &0&0 &0\\
1 &0&0   &0&0 &0\\
0 &1&1   &0 &1&1\\
0 &1&0   &0&0&0\\
0 &0&1  &0 &1&0\\
0 &0&0  &0 &0 &0\\
\end{array}

It would require more space and time to do the complete table recursively one by one. So instead at this point we can conclude that whenever column 4 or 5 has a "1" so should column 6 (definition of implication). So the implication does not hold for the case, A=T, B=T, C=F for example. The statement is false.

b) Statement: $(A\wedge B)\vee(\neg A\wedge C)\rightarrow (B\vee C)$

Proof:

\begin{array}{ccc|cccc}
A & B & C & (A\land B) \lor (\neg A \land C) & B\lor C\\
1 &1&1   &1&1 \\ 
1 &1&0   &1&1 \\
1 &0&1    &0&1 \\
1 &0&0   &0&0 \\
0 &1&1   &1&1\\
0 &1&0   &0&1\\
0 &0&1  &1 &1\\
0 &0&0  &0 &0\\
\end{array}

So this is correct as whenever 4th column has a 1, so does 5th.

Answer (score 2):

a) does not follow from 2), and a) is in fact not valid

If a) would be valid, then we would have:

$((A\wedge B)\vee (\neg A\wedge C))\color{red}\land (B\wedge C)=(A\wedge B)\vee(\neg A\wedge C)$

but that is not what 2) says.

Comment: If a) would be valid, we would have $\neg((A\wedge B)\vee (\neg A\wedge C))\color{red}\vee (B\wedge C)=(A\wedge B)\vee(\neg A\wedge C)$ as per the definition of implication: $x\rightarrow y=\neg x \vee y$, right?

Comment: Sorry.  I confused (a) and (1).  Clearly, (a) is not valid. As noted in my comment to the OP, the implication goes in the other direction.

Comment: @Mahesha999 Well, given that a) is not valid, everything would follow if it were, so I probably didn't put that very well. What I meant is just that you cannot infer $B \land C$ from $(A \land B) \lor (\neg A \land C)$, for if you could, then you would be able to get the conjunction as I indicated, but all you can get is the much weaker disjunction.